# LanguageExt: How do I do the equivalent of Option<T>.Match with a [Union]?

Tags: c#, functional-programming, language-ext

I want to create a union that will act a bit like `Option<T>`, but that allows a 3-way state, rather than a 2-way state. The reason for this is to use it when loading data from a database.

If I were doing this with an `Option<T>`, I would do something like this...

```cs
Option<Person> jimOpt = Option<Person>.None;
Person jimOpt = await _appDbContext.People.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == 1);
jimOpt.Match(person => {
    Console.WriteLine("Jim was found");
  },
  () => {
    Console.WriteLine("No such Jim");
  });
```

However, this doesn't distinguish between when the data is still loading and when the person is not found. This means that while the data is loading, the `Option` is in the `None` state, which gives the wrong impression in the UI, as it looks (briefly) as if the data was not found.

My idea is to create a `Union` like this...

```cs
[Union]
public interface Loading<T> {
  Loading<T> NotLoaded(); // Initial state, data not loaded yet
  Loading<T> Loaded(T value); // Data loaded successfully
  Loading<T> NotFound(); // Data access complete, but entity not found
}
```

...and do something like above, but setting it to be `NotLoaded<Person>` whilst the data access is going, and then either `Loaded<Person>` or `NotFound<Person>` when the data access has completed.

The problem is that the generated `Union` doesn't seem to have anything to help me here. I thought the idea of the code generation was to take away a lot of this grunt work.

Do I need to implement `Match`, `Map`, etc myself, or did I miss something in the code generation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Match` is now generated for `Union` types.  You can also use the c# `switch` expressions

Comment: Thanks Paul, I think we sorted this one out in the GitHub issues some time ago. I'd forgotten I asked here!